# clojure carmine redis connection errors

Tags: clojure, redis, redistogo, carmine

I've been plagued for a week with connection errors whenever I run my code outside of my local machine.

The connection errors are because carmine is connecting to localhost, no matter what I do. Here is the full output from a repl session, from my ns `store.core`, which `require`s  `[taoensso.carmine :as redis]`:

```
(def conn
  {:pool {}
   :spec {:url "redis://redistogo:[password]@chubb.redistogo.com:9836/"}})
#'store.core/conn

store.core=> (redis/wcar conn (redis/hget 1 2))
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Carmine connection error
```

**[enable local redis in another terminal]**

```
store.core=> (redis/wcar conn (redis/hget 1 2))
"3"
 ^ this is now connecting to my local redis, despite `conn` pointing to redistogo.
```

What am I doing wrong? This usage seems exactly as [carmine.clj#L28](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine/blob/master/src/taoensso/carmine.clj#L28) suggests!

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the author of carmine

> Could you possibly try with :uri instead of :url?

[source](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine/issues/194)

FML